# Distributing Finite Values Via Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, input

I'm attempting to create a Javscript game, and I'm a little stumped on a aspect of the "Character Creation" process.

My game has five points-based traits:

1. Endurance
2. Strength
3. Perception
4. Luck
5. Charisma

Each trait is set at "5" initially, and there are 5 available points to add. Obviously a total of 30 points.

I'm trying my absolute hardest to do this whole project with just plain vanilla javascript, no jQuery.

My question is how to create a form that allows you to distribute these. I had two ideas, but I'm not sure if the first one is practical without jQuery:
The first would be two have 5 text inputs, and have them update the "available points" when modified. I must confess, however, that I have no idea how to do this and have it live update without jQuery. The second would be to have plus or minus images that when clicked, updated the available points.

Anyone done something like this before?

Comment: Neither of those approaches is difficult. Find yourself an introductory JavaScript DOM tutorial and then ask a question here if you have a more specific problem.

Comment: Although it may result in more code, there's nothing DOM wise you can do with JQuery, that can't be completed with raw JS...

Comment: jQuery is plain javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to clean and sober VanillaJS! The withdrawal symptoms of JQuery dependence are painful but temporary.

```js
;(function (window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]');
    var maxPoints = 30;
    var availablePoints = 30;
    var o = document.querySelector('#o');

    var getTotal = function () {
        var total = 0;
        [].forEach.call(sliders, function (slider) {
            total = total + slider.valueAsNumber;
        });
        return total;
    };

    var handleChange = function (ev) {
        availablePoints = maxPoints - getTotal();
        if (availablePoints < 0) {
            this.value = this.dataset.lastKnownValue;
            availablePoints = 0;
        } else {
            this.dataset.lastKnownValue = this.valueAsNumber;
        }
        this.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML = this.value;
        o.innerHTML = availablePoints;
    };
    
    [].forEach.call(sliders, function (slider) {
        slider.addEventListener('input', handleChange);
        slider.dataset.lastKnownValue = 0;
    });

})(window, document);
```

```css
label {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
}
label input {
    float: right;
    width: 10em;
}
label span {
    color: red;
    width: 1em;
    float: right;
}
output {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
hr {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<form id="f">
    <label for="endurance">Endurance
        <input type="range" id="endurance" value="0" min="0" max="10" step="1" />
        <span>0</span>
    </label>
    <label for="strength">Strength
        <input id="strength" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" step="1" />
        <span>0</span>
    </label>
    <label for="perception">Perception
        <input id="perception" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" step="1" />
        <span>0</span>
    </label>
    <label for="luck">Luck
        <input id="luck" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" />
        <span>0</span>
    </label>
    <label for="charisma">Charisma
        <input id="charisma" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" step="1" />
        <span>0</span>
    </label>
</form>
<hr />Availible Points:
<output for="f" id="o"></output>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, sean9999. Again, apologies for the broad question. I just had no idea where to even start on this, as I hadn't found anything on the net about similar situations.

Comment: I've tried modifying your code a bit, so that it changes the max of the range inputs depending on the amount of remaining points. My issue is that I can't figure out how to select the value of each individual input, and adding the "availiblePoints" to it, while changing all of the max's at once. Any ideas? Here's what I have so far on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLuwa2z2/

Comment: i think changing the max value would not be a suitable approach because it would present UI problems (setting the slider all the way to the right in some cases would mean 10, and in other cases less). I solved this by adding a `lastKnownValue` to each element, and setting the input back to that value if the total values exceed 30. So your range slider "snaps back" if you try to set an illegal value.  http://jsfiddle.net/sean9999/7zhox1r8/3/

Comment: Wow! That's awesome. Thanks so much, I hadn't even thought of that.